# NodeJs crypto scrambles text on subsequent decrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I have these two methods for encryption and decryption:

```
function encrypt(text, guid){
    var textBuffer = new Buffer(text, 'utf8');
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr',guid);
    cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
    cipher.write(textBuffer);
    cipher.end();
    var cipheredText = cipher.read().toString('hex');
    return cipheredText;
}

function decrypt(encrypted, guid){
    try{
        var hexBuffer = new Buffer(encrypted, 'hex');
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ctr',guid);
        decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
        decipher.write(hexBuffer);
        decipher.end();
        var decipheredText = decipher.read().toString('utf8');
        return decipheredText;
    }catch(error){
        return "";
    }
}
```

When the call to "decrypt" is within few seconds of "encrypt", it deciphers well, but when the call takes few minutes to get called again, it deciphers text into something else. 
What could I be doing wrong? Parameters are same.

Comment: *"it deciphers well, but when the call takes few minutes to get called again, it deciphers text into something else"* This suggests that you're overwriting the ciphertext file in the mean time. Please check your other code and please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for replying, but here there is no file involved. The two parameters here are plain strings.

Comment: As I said, there is no apparent problem with the code that you've shown, so the issue must be somewhere else.